# Can DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode skip selection of anchor tag events?

Tags: asp.net, xpath, selectsinglenode, xpathdocument

Given the following...

```
HtmlNode myDiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='someid']");
```

...where the resulting *myDiv.InnerHtml* contains:

```
<span>...other content I want to consume...</span>
<a href="http://www.somewhere.com" onmousedown="return somefunc('random','parm','values','SHXA213')">Click Me</a>
<span>...and more content I want to consume...</span>
```

Is there a way to **not** select the *onmousedown* portion of the anchor tag?

**Solution**
What I needed to do was the following:

```
HtmlNodeCollection anchors = myDiv.SelectNodes(@"//a[@class='someclass']");
anchors[0].SetAttributeValue("onmousedown", "");

// could have also used anchors[0].Attributes.Remove() or .RemoveAt()
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish?  Why is the onmousedown bad in your scenario?  If your using the results of SelectSingleNode, you can ignore any child nodes/attributes that you don't care about.  I have a feeling there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Sure, I'm scraping some search results from Google. I need the InnerHtml contents pretty much as-is from a single div. The onmousedown throws javascript errors in the context of the site I'm consuming these results into. I figured SelectSingleNode would allow a way to ignore attributes but I have not been able to find the syntax yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to not select the
>   onmousedown portion of the anchor tag?

**No. Not with XPath** (`SelectSingleNode`).

XPath is a query language and it cannot modify the nodes selected by an XPath expression. You need an additional language (DOM or XSLT) to change nodes (eg. strip off attributes).

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I found what I was looking for and will update my post accordingly.